# Subgroups within a dataframe based on neighboring properties to an element

Tags: r, datetime, conditional-statements, sapply

I have this data structure below and need to create a column based on the associations to element A within a half hour before and after, as well as being present in neighboring areas (neighbor is defined as +1 and -1 of the area).

```
ind area time
B   5   3/12/1981 7:20
D   6   3/12/1981 7:25
A   5   3/12/1981 7:40
B   4   3/12/1981 7:40
A   7   8/29/1982 10:00
A   31  9/12/1982 9:50
C   30  9/12/1982 9:50
A   69  4/10/1985 13:37
```

The desired result is a column with the instances where an individual occurs within the specified range (within half hour before/after individual A is present as well as within an interval of +1 and -1 of the area where individual A is present).
Ideally, it would look like this:

```
ind area    time    instance
B   5   3/12/1981 7:20  1
D   6   3/12/1981 7:25  1
A   5   3/12/1981 7:40  1
B   4   3/12/1981 7:40  1
A   7   8/29/1982 10:00 2
A   31  9/12/1982 9:50  3
C   30  9/12/1982 9:50  3
A   69  4/10/1985 13:37 4
```

An instance, in this case, is when individual A is present, along with any other individual present within the conditionals of time and area. If A shows up alone without any neighbors by area and time, it gains an instance of its own, as shown in instance 2 and 4.

In terms of code, I considered it simpler to copy the date-time of the occurrence of individual A into the column as such:

```
ind area    time    instance
B   5   3/12/1981 7:20  3/12/1981 7:40
D   6   3/12/1981 7:25  3/12/1981 7:40
A   5   3/12/1981 7:40  3/12/1981 7:40
B   4   3/12/1981 7:40  3/12/1981 7:40
A   7   8/29/1982 10:00 8/29/1982 10:00
A   31  9/12/1982 9:50  9/12/1982 9:50
C   30  9/12/1982 9:50  9/12/1982 9:50
A   69  4/10/1985 13:37 4/10/1985 13:37
```

Which works as well in my particular situation.
I can't quite figure this out mainly from lack of dexterity with syntax allied to the nature of the problem at hand. From my understanding, a simple `ifelse` statement will not work and I am not sure how an `sapply` may be combined with it.

Quick construction of the example data:

```
id<-c("B","D","A","B","A","A","C","A")
area<-c(5,6,5,4,7,31,30,69)
time<-as.POSIXct(c("3/12/1981 7:20","3/12/1981 7:25","3/12/1981 7:40","3/12/1981 7:40","8/29/1982 10:00","9/12/1982 9:50","9/12/1982 9:5
                   0","4/10/1985 13:37"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

dat<-data.frame(id, area, time)
```

My attempt came down to this, but it felt wrong from the get-go:

```
    dat$instance <- with(dat, sapply(time[ind==A], function(x) 
 ifelse(abs(area- area[ind==A & time == x]) <=1 & abs(difftime(time, x, units = "mins")) <= 30, time[ind=A],NA)
             )
)
```

It is an attempt to adapt codes provided by *Henrik*, *thelatemail* and *Justin* for a problem I had a few months ago based on a similar issue but involving subsetting.
Apologies if there is an equivalent problem already listed. I did not succeed in finding one I could interpret.

Comment: The description is clear now, thank you ) this is an interesting question. Btw, you have some obvious mistakes in your attempt: in `time[ind=A]` it should be double equal sign `==`, and `A` should be coded as `"A"` everywhere, because that is a string object. I don't think it fixes all the problems though

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
instance <- as.data.frame(with(dat, sapply(time[id=="A"], function(x) 
 ifelse(abs(area- area[id=="A" & time == x]) <=1 & abs(difftime(time, x, units = "mins")) <= 30, x,NA))))

datinstance=cbind(dat,instance)
melt(datinstance, id.vars=c("id","time","area"),na.rm=T)
```

The melt procedure might take care of possible duplicates of A within time/area requisites.